# Change IP address in Cisco Prime infrastructure

Tags: cisco, management

Is it possible to change the Cisco Prime Infrastructure platform's IP address after PI has been installed ?

This [reference in the docs](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/prime_infrastructure/2-0/command/reference/cli20/cli20_appendix_011.html#wp8796098100) seems to indicate that you can.

```
ncs/admin(config)# interface GigabitEthernet 1
ncs/admin(config-GigabitEthernet)# ip address 209.165.200.227 255.255.255.224
Changing the hostname or IP may result in undesired side effects,
such as installed application(s) being restarted.
........
To verify that NCS processes are running, use the
'show application status ncs' command.
```

Personnally, I would proceed by first shutting down the NCS services, then modify the IP, and then restart the NCS services. I think it can be done that way with minimal damage.

The point of my asking is : What would happen to the PI configuration and the polling of the data, when I change the ip of the NCS server?